# Creating JUnit Test for JMS to test if MessageListener onMessage() method was called after jms.convertAndSend()

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, spring-jms, spring-boot-test

I am trying to create a Unit test for `onMessage()` method of a `MessageListener` component class. This `onMessage()` method was annotated with `@JmsListener`

The JUnit Test `onMessageShouldReceiveMessageOnJMSSend()` I created should pass if `Message` argument of `onMessage(Message message)` from **javax.jms.Message** is being received. In other words, when `message` is not null and when `onMessage()` is called.

**MessageListener.java**

```
package com.myapp.listener;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.myapp.service.MessageTransformService;

@Component
public class MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private MessageTransformService messageService;

    @JmsListener(destination = "MY.QUEUE.DEV")
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                String xmlMessage = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                messageService.transformMessageToOldSchema(xmlMessage);
            } catch (JMSException | TransformerConfigurationException | IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Below, I created a **MessageListenerTestContextConfiguration** class which I imported in **MessageListenerTest.java** using `@Import({ MessageListenerTestContextConfiguration.class })`

**MessageListenerTestContextConfiguration.java**

```
package com.myapp.testconfig;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@TestConfiguration
@EnableJms
public class MessageListenerTestContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
    
}
```

**MessageListenerTest.java**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import javax.jms.Message;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.myapp.config.AppConfig;
import com.myapp.config.MessageListenerTestContextConfiguration;
import com.myapp.listener.MessageListener;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import({ MessageListenerTestContextConfiguration.class })
public class MessageListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private MessageListener messageListener;
    
    @Test
    public void onMessageShouldReceiveMessageOnJMSSend() {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("MY.QUEUE.DEV", "Test Message");
        Message msg = mock(Message.class);
        verify(messageListener, times(1)).onMessage(msg); //this is line 42 mentioned in console message
    }
}
```

When I run the test method `onMessageShouldReceiveMessageOnJMSSend()`, it says

> -> at MessageListenerTest.onMessageShouldReceiveMessageOnJMSSend(MessageListenerTest.java:42)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

From the message on console, it doesn't look like `onMessage()` is being invoked from **MessageListener** class after I send a message with `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend()`

The console message points to this line : `verify(messageListener, times(1)).onMessage(msg);`

In my **application.properties** on both **src/main/resources** and **src/test/resources**, I have the following

**application.properties**

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

I can also see, activemq is running and active.

I'd appreciate any comments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are doing the verification too quickly; you need to somehow wait until the message has been received (e.g. by injecting a mock `MessageTransformService` that counts down a latch, and wait for it in your test).
2. This will never work...

   ```
    Message msg = mock(Message.class);
    verify(messageListener, times(1)).onMessage(msg);
   ```

The listener will never receive that mock message, use `onMessage(any())` instead (or use an `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the actual message received, so you can test its properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gary. I tried `any()` but got the same error. I will read about `ArgumentCaptor` since I haven't used that before.

Comment: It is more important for your test to wait until the listener is called.